# Read letters of different languages in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $string_test = "Ã¢Â‰Âˆdne";
    $sql = "SELECT gender, encoded_names FROM tbl WHERE encoded_names='".$string_test."'";
```

The query executes correctly when I try in "sql" section of phpmyadmin but couldn't execute on browser.
I tried different functions like utf8-encode ,utf8_decode etc but none of them worked to execute this query.
What should I do to get this query work ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: You cannot concatenate strings and expect things to work, that leads to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.